# stubbing api request in async series

Tags: node.js, testing, sinon

I have a module which resizes an image, `imageResizer`, using `graphicsmagick` and another module, `apiCaller`, which has two functions, one for a `get` request and another for a `post` request, using the `request` module.
In `imageResizer` I call `apiCaller.get`, a function which triggers the image resizing is then called if the get request is successful and then if that goes alright `apiCaller.post` is called.

It is somethings like this:

```
exports.imageResizer = function (arguments) {

    async.series([
      function(callback) {
         apiCaller.get(callback);
      },
      function(callback) {
         gm("filepath")
          .resize("sizes")
          .write("destinationPath", function (err) {
            if(err) // do something
          }, callback());
      },
      function(callback) {
         apiCallerPost(arguments)
      }
    ]);
}
```

---

```
apiCaller = {};

apiCaller.get = function (arguments, callback) {
   // setup variables and stuff
   function _callback (error, response, body) {
     if (error) {// do somethind}
     else {callback(null, body}
   }

   request.get(options, _callback);
}

module.exports = apiCaller;
```

My question his which would be the best approach to testing this?
Would stubbing `apiCaller.get` and `apiCaller.post` be the best approach? What about the `request` module itself? Would that need to be stubbed too?

I am using `sinon`, `chai`, `mocha` and `proxyquire`.